# Scheduling Dependent Jobs in Contol-M

Tags: control-m

I have a flow that needs to be trigger automatically on Tuesday every week.

In this, I have 4 jobs all dependent on each other.

JobA<-JobB<-JobC<-JobD

I have put all 4 jobs in one SMART folder.

Now I have scheduled this flow so that as soon as a job gets completed another job should trigger.

How can I achieve it.

Comment: Probably I don't get the question, but: you can schedule the smart folder every Tuesday .

Answer (score 0):

Control-M has a design element called "**Conditions**" that defines the flowchart of a process mesh. These conditions determine the Jobs that are successors and predecessors through the Input and Output Conditions.

Keep in mind that a Condition in Control-M is a prerequisite for the execution of a Job and is composed of the following elements:

- A Name,
- A date
- A sign